# Preserve styling when exporting HTML in Jupyter notebook.

Tags: python, html, ipython, jupyter

I have some customised CSS for my `Jupyter` notebook. And I am trying export one of my `ipynb` file to `HTML`.

While most of the thing looks identical. The input area is different.

In ipynb, it looks like:

[image: In ipynb it looks like:]

in HTML, it looks like:

[image: In HML it looks like:]

I found it is caused by nbconvert converting the HTML class attributes. However, the conversion is not one-to-one. For example, `cm.builtin` and `cm.varilable` are both converted to `n` and `string` could be converted to either `s1` or `s2`.

What should I do to make sure the HTML outputs like identical to its ipynb counterpart?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/447 refers to the same issue.